# pow of OpenCV Mat with negative elements

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I've tried to convert some codes from `MATLAB` to `c++` with `OpenCV` but I got stuck in this line :
`MATLAB` code :

```
t3 = real((ISimMatrix .* QSimMatrix) .^ 0.02)
```

I re implemented this line in c++ with:

```
cv::Mat t2, t3;
t2 = ISimMatrix.mul(QSimMatrix);
cv::pow(t2, lambda, t3);
```

both `ISimMatrix` and `QSimMatrix` are 2D double matrix that might contain negative numbers, The problem is when the multiple of them power to 0.02, In `MATLAB` result is 2D complex matrix but in `OpenCV` result is `Mat_<double>` witch some elements are nan that cause all next calculations go wrong.

How can I implement pow function that support negative power ?

thanks.

Comment: OpenCV doesn’t do complex numbers very well. You will probably need to use a different library for this. My DIPlib will do it, otherwise try a linear algebra library like Eigen.

Answer (score 1):

Use different library could be an option of course, but after some searches about complex numbers in c++ I wrote simple function to solve problem :

```
inline cv::Mat cpow(cv::Mat m, double o) {
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec2f> out = cv::Mat_<cv::Vec2f>(m.rows, m.cols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.rows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m.cols; j++)
        {           
            std::complex<double> b(m.at<double>(i, j), 0);
            std::complex<double> p(o, 0);
            std::complex<double> r = std::pow(b, p);
            out.at<cv::Vec2f>(i, j) = cv::Vec2f(r.real(), r.imag());
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: `m.at<double>(i, j)` is quite expensive though. You should obtain a pointer and the step value, and use those to access all pixels. I think OpenCV also has an iterator for images that would be much more efficient than accessing each pixel with `at`.

Answer (score 1):

May be it's too late and you have a working solution, but just wanted to write up my answer for fun.

If you want to do it the opencv way, here's how:

Let's write your number in the polar form. Your `y` will be always zero as your numbers are all real.

```
x + i.y = r.exp(i.theta) = r.(cos(theta) + i.sin(theta)
```

where, `r = sqrt(x*x + y*y), theta = atan2(y, x)`

Raising it to the power `p`:

```
(x + i.y)^p = (r.exp(i.theta))^p = r^p . exp(i.theta.p)
```

So, use `cartToPolar` to get the polar form, raise the magnitude(=r) to power `p` using `pow` as you no longer get negative values for the magnitude, multiply the angle by `p`, then use `polarToCart` to get your solution.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
Mat re = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
Mat im = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
re.at<double>(0, 0) = 2;
re.at<double>(1, 1) = -2;
Mat r, theta;
cartToPolar(re, im, r, theta);

cout << "real:\n";
cout << re << endl;
cout << "r:\n";
cout << r << endl;
cout << "theta:\n";
cout << theta << endl;

double p = 0.02;
Mat new_r, new_theta;
pow(r, p, new_r);
cout << "new_r:\n";
cout << new_r << endl;
new_theta = p * theta;
cout << "new_theta:\n";
cout << new_theta << endl;

Mat new_re, new_im;
polarToCart(new_r, new_theta, new_re, new_im);
cout << "new_re:\n";
cout << new_re << endl;
cout << "new_im:\n";
cout << new_im << endl;
```

Output:

```
real:
[2, 0, 0;
 0, -2, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
r:
[2, 0, 0;
 0, 2, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
theta:
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 3.141592741012573, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
new_r:
[1.013959479790043, 6.933081232643711e-07, 6.933081232643711e-07;
 6.933081232643711e-07, 1.013959479790043, 6.933081232643711e-07;
 6.933081232643711e-07, 6.933081232643711e-07, 6.933081232644603e-07]
new_theta:
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0.06283185482025147, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
new_re:
[1.013959479790043, 6.933081232643711e-07, 6.933081232643711e-07;
 6.933081232643711e-07, 1.011958843888384, 6.933081232643711e-07;
 6.933081232643711e-07, 6.933081232643711e-07, 6.933081232644603e-07]
new_im:
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0.06366705860016499, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
```